# Prove that if A is symmetric and invertible, then$ (A^{-1})^t = (A^t)^{-1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a problem. Prove that if A is symmetric and invertible, then $(A^{-1})^t = (A^t)^{-1}$.
This is what I have done, please tell me if it is correct:

Say $C=A^{-1}$. Then, $C^t = ((C^{-1})^t)^{-1} = ((C^{-1})^{-1})^t = C^t$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $A$ is an invertible matrix (symmetric or not symmetric) then

$$AA^{-1}=I\Rightarrow \left(AA^{-1}\right)^T=\left(A^{-1}\right)^TA^T=I$$
so the matrix $A^T$ is invertible and 
$$\left(A^T\right)^{-1}=\left(A^{-1}\right)^T$$